# Reset Custom URl handler

Tags: javascript, windows, registry, url-scheme

I am developing a desktop application that handle clicks on custom URL in a web site, The custom URL protocol is : **odwaa://**
When the user click on the link, **MyApp.exe** that handle the custom protocol is launched. Till now everything is ok and work perfectly.

To verify that the application is or is not installed i use Javascript code to check if the custom URL protocol is known or not, if not then the desktop Application **MyApp.exe** is downloaded automatically else **MyApp.exe** is launched.

What i faced as an issue is that when the user uninstall the desktop application, and then he/she click on the link the automatic download doesn't fire and i get the prompt dialog as shown below.

[image]
Javascript code :

```
try {
        var customURI = "odwaa://test/";
        var iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenIframe");
        iframe.contentWindow.location.href = customURI;
    } catch (e) {
        //work in firefox 
        console.log(e);
        if (e.name == "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL") {
            window.open('/odwaa/setup_odwaa.exe', '_blank');
        } else {
            window.open(customURI, '_blank');
        }
    }
```

I have checked the registry,no entry with **odwaa** key or value exist.

Could someone help me please.
P.S: i use Inno Setup

Best Regards